# Kotlin unexpected value of assignment

Tags: kotlin

Having trouble with lambdas and function links strange behavior. 
See comments in code:

```
class User() {
    var i = 0

    fun simpleFoo() {
        println("Unit")
    }
}

class Either {
    lateinit var b: User

    fun foo(fnR: (User) -> Any): Any = fnR(b)
}

class A {
    fun main() {
        val either = Either<User>()
        either.foo(::handleUser) // works fine
        either.foo() { user ->
            user.i = 3 // Expected value of type Any
        }
    }

    fun handleUser(user: User) {
        user.simpleFoo()
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, my misunderstood, corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because assignment in Kotlin is not expression. So it doesn't return Unit.

Workaround is to just use function link

```
either.foo(::handleUser) // works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Function link like `either.foo(::handleUser)` is fine but if you want to use lambda expression then in your case you did a mistake. Your function

```
fun foo(fnR: (User) -> Any): Any = fnR(b)
```

receives a function that returns a value of type `Any` so you must have to return a value of type `Any` from your lambda (you forgot to return a value) like:

```
either.foo() { user ->
    user.i = 3 // Expected value of type Any
    user // You should return a value as Any and here I returned user as Any
}
```